# Detecting if react app opened via desktop browser event using mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, browser

Currently i'm using library called 'react-device-detect' to detect if my react app is opened via browser, mobile browser or tablet browser. Everything looks fine until i used desktop browser with mobile view selected (samsung galaxy 5, in inspect element).

Since i have feature that allow user to take a selfie with their Identity Card, so i don't want the user to select/pick the file from gallery to avoid uploading someone else Identity Card.

So this is the scenarios:

1. User opens the app on mobile devices browser (Android/Iphone/Ipad/etc), when user click the button, it will immediately open the native camera app. (mobile browser is detected)
2. User opens the app via desktop browser (chrome/safari) on laptop/PC, when user click the button, it will show error because we don't want user to pick imge/file from computer. (browser desktop is detected)

the scenario 1 and 2 are run as expected. But, when i open the app via mobile view on desktop/laptop browser, it will detect the browser as Mobile browser so when i click the button, it will fallback by opening the finder/window explorer to pick an image/file which is i don't want to

here is the code

```
<input
    ref={imagePicker}
    type='file'
    accept='image/*'
    capture={true}
    onChange={onImageReceived}
 />
```

So my question: Is it possible **to detect mobile view (on desktop browser) as a regular desktop browser** ?

*note: detecting using user-agent is also not possible since mobile view on desktop browser will also mimicking user-agent for selected device*

Thanks in advance